# Tailwindcss not changing style on local font

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to use Gilroy font throughout my application. I added Gilroy font. Gilroy font is working but tailwindcss is not able to change anything like color and weight of the text. Also it is using thin font on everything like inside p tags, h tags and everywhere it is using Thin font.

Here is my folder structure:
[image]

```
Here is the layout.tsx file:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import localFont from "next/font/local";
import "./globals.css";

const gilroy = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "./fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-Thin.ttf",
      weight: "100",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-ThinItalic.ttf",
      weight: "100",
      style: "italic",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-Regular.ttf",
      weight: "400",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-RegularItalic.ttf",
      weight: "400",
      style: "italic",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-Bold.ttf",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/gilroy/Gilroy-BoldItalic.ttf",
      weight: "700",
      style: "italic",
    },
  ],
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Description",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={gilroy.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `tailwind.config.js` file because it conflicts with the `tailwind.config.ts` file.

Also, check the `tailwind.config.ts` file's content property. This file should look like this at first,

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

Comment: I am using src directory so I should have added "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", in tailwind.config.js